# Noncommutative analog compact open topology

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Recall that for any locally compact Hausdorff topological space $X$, there is so called compact open topology on $C(X)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology. Is there a noncommutative analog of this topology? I mean is there a noncommutative analog of this for $C^*$ algebras?